# Same as vlookup but cloumn number is changing everyday

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to excel macros.I have Sheet1 and Sheet2. Both the sheets have Project Id as common. I have columns in sheet1 as cd1 and cd2 which are same as cd1 and cd2 in sheet2 but values are not in order. I can do VLOOKUP here but the cd1 and cd2 might be changing.In sheet2 the column Cd1 was in Column X yesterday  and now it is in Column Z. My problem is if I do Vlookup here then i have to change all the column numbers and column name everyday. Is there any pocedure that I track those values using Column Names??

I think this is simple but don't know how to do it. Thanks in Advance.[Sheet 1 and Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkSHi.png)

Comment: This may be a limitation of `Vlookup()`, give `Index/Match` a try ([tutorial here](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/), and of course Google).

Comment: When you say column Names I assume the first row has titles?

Comment: Yes, My excel  has headers.

Comment: @BruceWayne I think Index Match will not work here because the columns will be changing. I dont know Cd1 column shifts to which column tomorrow. It was in Column F before and now it is in Column X

Comment: Is there any way I can track those values using Column Titles Cd1 and Cd2  ??

Comment: Please mock up some data, it is hard to determine what you want.

Comment: Put it in the original post using edit.

Comment: You can use the `match` to find where your columns are moving. So long as you have a header, or *some* way to identify that column.

Answer (score 1):

This formula will not care what column the columns are except the Project which I assumed is Column A on both sheets:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$DD,0,MATCH(B$1,Sheet2!$1:$1,0)),MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0))
```

copy over and down as needed.  It will refer to the headers on Sheet 1 and find the matching header on sheet two.

[image: ![enter image description here]

For reference here is Sheet2:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Then no matter what the column it should find the correct value.

Comment: This is little bit confusing. I have to compare it with my Project Id. Look up value is Project Id.

Comment: I am doing it wrong I think. it sis giving me value 0. What is $1:$1??

Comment: $1:$1 is row 1.  It is the row in which my titles reside. @Rehaan  outside of that I do not know what to do to help.  As you can see in my images, it works for me.  Make sure the titles are are spelled exactly the same.

Comment: Can you post the exact formula you are currently using in the comment below? @Rehaan